# Insert data into multiple tables from one select statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert data into two different tables via a select statement.This select statement is calling an inline TVF.

What I have so far is :

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2 (RowNumber, ValFromUser, ColumnName, ValFromFunc, FuncWeight, percentage)
  SELECT 
     RowNumber, @hospitalname, 'hospitalname', 
     PercentMatch, @constVal, PercentMatch * @constVal 
  FROM   
     dbo.Matchhospitalname (@hospitalname)
```

But there are certain columns that need to be supplied to a permanent table `dbo.Cache`.

Above mentioned query is called multiple times in the procedure.

```
Insert into dbo.Cache(StringSearched, ColName, RowId, PercentMatch) 
   select 
      ValFromUser, ColumnName, RowNumber, Max(ValFromFunc) as Percentage    
   from 
      #Temp2 
   group by 
      ValFromUser, ColumnName, RowNumber
```

Adding data into `dbo.Cache` separately as above would make all the previously added values to be added as many times as this statement is executed which is of course not desirable.

May be if it is not possible at all to add data to two tables via one select, we can do something like adding only those rows that were added in last insert statement only ?

Can I get some directions on this, please?

Edit : As suggested, I tried using OUTPUT INTO this way but Group by seems to be at the wrong place.The grouped rowsare to be inserted only in `dbo.Cache` and not in `#Temp2`

How do I solve this ?

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2 (RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,ValFromFunc,FuncWeight,percentage)OUTPUT
    INSERTED.ValFromUser,
    INSERTED.ColumnName,
    INSERTED.RowNumber,
    MAX(INSERTED.ValFromFunc)
  INTO dbo.CACHE
  (StringSearched, ColName, RowId, PercentMatch)
  Group By Inserted.ValFromUser, Inserted.ColumnName, Inserted.RowNumber 
      SELECT RowNumber,@firstname,'firstname',PercentMatch,@constVal,PercentMatch * @constVal FROM   dbo.MatchFirstName(@firstname)
```

Comment: try using and OUPTUT ... INTO clause

Comment: @KM.: Thank you. That helped. But could you please check the update ? I am stuck with syntax for group by clause .

Comment: for each row in the INSERT, you get one row in the OUTPUT INTO.  you can't GROUP BY the OUTPUT INTO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via an output clause or more typically you can put a trigger on a table. In other words you can create an after insert trigger on temp table '#temp2'. I have never seen a trigger on a temp table but its possible. You will have to recreate the trigger every time the temp table is recreated. Remember that #temp2 will only exist (and be visible) in the session that it is created in.

Comment: A trigger cannot be created on a temporary or system table, although triggers can reference temporary tables. System tables should not be referenced; use the Information Schema Views instead. For more information,. This is coming from here : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214593(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: @Hogan: Could you please check the update ?Where do  I fit the group by clause ?